# Adding title back to Android window when using PhoneGap

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova

I'm building an app using PhoneGap, which calls

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in the parent onCreate (DroidGap).  But, I want to add the title back on so I can use an ActionBar.  Is there any flag/way to reset this feature back?  If worst comes to worst, I can modify the entire DroidGap class, but would like to still use their version.

And in case it helps anyone to see what DroidGap does in its onCreate, here's the link: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android/blob/master/framework/src/com/phonegap/DroidGap.java

ActionBar code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.main);
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); super.init();
ActionBar bar = getActionBar(); 
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); // here NPE is thrown
bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Some Text").setTabListener(new CustomTabListener()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up not being able to solve this without modifying the original code.  What I ended up doing was copying the DroidGap class into my own class (source code linked in the post) and commented out the following line:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Then, I extended my normal activity with my modified version of DroidGap, not PhoneGap's version.

Then, in my activity's onCreate, I have something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Home").setTabListener(new CustomTabListener()));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Something").setTabListener(new CustomTabListener()));

    loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

Without the requestFeature, you'll get `null` from the `getActionBar()`.

Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 4):

Phonegap / Cordova version 1.9 added a flag to toggle this feature:

```
if(!this.getBooleanProperty("showTitle", false))
{
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
```

Example onCreate method that enables window title:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // enable window title for actionbar support
    super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
}
```

Comment: The order is important for this to work,   You need to do super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true); before calling super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);.  The title will be displayed if using Cordova 1.9.0.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tested `FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE`?

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
getWindow().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
```

or try loading Theme with title bar:

```
setTheme(android.R.style.choose some of the themes listed or create your own);
```

Comment: Yeah... just did.  But, I got the "You cannot combine titles with other title features" exception.

Comment: `getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.main);`

Comment: Hmm... just tried that too.  It must be that the DroidGap is adding it back again somewhere.  Also, when I try to snag the ActionBar, I get an NPE. Any ideas?

Comment: Code added to post and NPE is on bar.setNavigationMode

Comment: Hmmm...thats why the `ActionBar object` is null. You need to set the container of that action bar. Try `setContentView(R.layout.main);` before you call `getActionBar()` I assumed you have your actionbar there. Or do `ActionBar bar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionb);`

Comment: That's actually why I have the super.init(), as that does fire setContentView. And R.id.actionb (or android.R.id.actionb) doesn't seem to be defined.  Maybe I can't do it with the way PhoneGap works. :-\

Answer (score 0):

Check the Android Manifest. I found that phonegap generates an Android manifest that specifies android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar". Changing this theme allowed me to control the title display from code.