# Not able to get android icon and project name in emmulator header

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I am new to Cordova and I am creating an app using Cordova(Android). But when I run the program every thing is working fine except the android icon and my project name is missing from the header secton in the emmulator.

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="VerticalList.css">
    <title>Notification Prompt Dialog Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Empty
    }

    // process the promptation dialog result
    function onPrompt(results) {
        alert("You selected button number " + results.buttonIndex + " and entered " + results.input1);
    }

    // Show a custom prompt dialog
    //
    function showPrompt() {
        navigator.notification.prompt(
            'Please enter your name',  // message
            onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
            'Registration',            // title
            ['Ok','Exit'],             // buttonLabels
            'Jane Doe'
                       // defaultText
        );
    }

    </script>
  </head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="vertical">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="showPrompt(); return false;"> Home</a>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Encounter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Medications</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weight</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blood Pressure</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blood Sugar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lab And Test Results</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Office Visit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Office Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Data Analysis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Appointment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Allergy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Problem</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

  </nav>
  </div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
And this is my css file:
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background:#eee;
    color: #444;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

div.wrapper {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 350px;
}

nav.vertical {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
}

  nav.vertical > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }

    nav.vertical > ul > li {
      display: block;
    }

      nav.vertical > ul > li > a {
        background-color: rgb(157, 34, 60);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(157, 34, 60));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(157, 34, 60));
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(157, 34, 60));
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(157, 34, 60));
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
        display: block;
        font-size: .85rem;
        font-weight: 500;
        height: 50px;
        letter-spacing: .5rem;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        transition: all .1s ease;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

        nav.vertical > ul > li > a:hover {
         background-color: rgb(114, 51, 98);
         background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
         background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
         background-image: -o-linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98));
         background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(114, 51, 98), rgb(114, 51, 98)); 
         cursor: pointer;
        }

          nav.vertical > ul > li > div {
            background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
          }

          nav.vertical > ul > li > div > ul {
            list-style-type: none;
          }

            nav.vertical > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {
             background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
             border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
             color: #333331;
             display: block;
             font-size: 1.1rem;
             padding: 10px 0;
             text-decoration: none;
             transition: all 0.15s linear;
            }

              nav.vertical > ul > li > div > ul > li:hover > a {
                background-color: lightBlue;
                color: rgb(255,255,255);
                padding: 10px 0 10px 50px;
              }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding title back to Android window when using PhoneGap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225593/adding-title-back-to-android-window-when-using-phonegap)

Comment: Actually i am new to Android also,so can you please help me out on what and all changes are required in my .java file

Comment: This is my java file:public class HelloWorld extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
  super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/History.html", 2000);

Comment: add this `super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true);` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: i have added that but still its not showing :(